# Marshal an object as one of its properties with Jackson (as for value objects i.e primitive types wrappers)

Tags: java, xml, json, jackson

**EDIT:** Previous answer does not work (it stills create a nested object)
I'm using Jersey and Jackson.

I got a class like

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Name {
   private String value;
   @XmlValue
   public String getValue(){...}
   public void setValue(String value){...}
}
```

used as in

```
public class Person{

   @XmlElement(name = "IDName")
   public Name getName(){...}
}
```

I'd like to marshal Name object as the value of it's identity property.
How can I achieve that?

```
<Person>
  <IDName>foo</IDName>
</Person>
```

instead of

```
<Person>
  <IDName>
      <Value>foo</Value>
  </IDName>
</Person>
```

I'd tried both to indicate in Person that Name object should be marshalled as itself.getValue() and either to indicate within Name class to marshal without any element wrapper (its fields directly) with no luck.

Comment: Sorry I looked for it really hard could not find wording for same question. Thanks, i'll close it!

Comment: I found it. Using jackson+jersey, I am forced to use '@JsonValue' Jackson annotation in place of '@XmlValue'. The later does not work. Using the exact same code as in my sample and adding '@JsonValue' makes it work.

Comment: I have re-opened the question. I have updated the title & tags to reflect that this is a Jackson question and not a JAXB question, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it is a Jackson-provider question but the solution seeked was about using standard JAXB annotations processed by Jackson. It's a pity we need to rely on the whole Jackson dependency just because of this workaround (@JsonValue), the rest works flawlessly with JAXB annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is replacing @XmlValue annotation with Jackson's @JsonValue to make it work (tested). 
I infer from http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations that it can be the only solution for now

According to this the official documentation

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue
The field/property to which this annotation is applied will be named "value".
```

So maybe it's limited by design. Any better answer, specially if using JAXB annotations alone, will be much appreciated